# 2 connections on personal hotspot

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, tethering, mac-address

Odd problem here. I just turned on my hotspot and after a few minutes the blue ribbon is claiming that there are 2 connections. I am not at home, and my phone isn't hooked up to my computer.

When I saw that there were two connections, I fired up kali and monitored my network. Sure enough, there were two stations... **with the same MAC address.**

How is this possible?

Comment: What exactly was in the arp table? iCloud can have multiple devices connect so it might be harmless. What happens when you choose a new key to join the SSID?

Answer (score 2):

Apple devices using iOS8 (and presumably later) allocates random MAC when browsing hotspots to prevent phones being tracked. It is possible that some other device has already used that MAC.